# Archers and Pikemen (CODEMASTERS) (Codechef)

Tags: algorithm

There was a recent contest on codechef named CODEMASTER (which has just ended a few minutes back, so I can put this question on a forum now, I believe :P ).
The question is Archers and Pikemen.

This is the problem statement::

> You are being attacked by hostile enemy forces, with knights and
>   swordsmen charging at you. Being the commander of your unit, you have
>   been given the task of arranging your elite archers and   pikemen in a
>   special formation.
>
> The archers and pikemen must stand between two flag posts in a
>   straight line (no soldier can  stand beyond the flags). Each archer
>   must have at least two pikemen by his side (one to his left and one to
>   his right)   such that he is at equal distances from both of them. (A
>   pikeman may be shared between two archers).
>
> The archers stand at given fixed positions and the separations between
>   them may not be equal. You need to position your troops in the given
>   formation using the minimum number of pikemen.
>
> Assume that the minimum distance between a pikeman and an archer or a
>   pikeman and a flag is 1  unit. the minimum distance between two
>   archers is 2 units. Input
>
> The first line of the input contains an integer T denoting the number
>   of test cases. The  description of T test cases follow.
>
> The second line contains an integer N denoting the number of
>   separations.
>
> The following N lines each contain an integer x, which is the
>   separation of the current archer  from the previous one.
>
> The first value of x is the separation of the first archer from the
>   first flag. The last value of  x is the separation between the last
>   archer and the second flag   Output
>
> For each test case, output a single line containing the minimum number
>   of pikemen required. Constraints
>
> ```
> 1 ≤ T ≤ 1000
> 1 ≤ N ≤ 1000
> 2 ≤ x ≤ 1000
> ```
>
> Example
>
> Input:
>
> 2 3 4 4 2 4 2 2 2 2
>
> Output:
>
> 3 4
>
> Explanation
>
> Example case 1: A possible formation can be :
>   F---1---p---3---A---3---p---1---A---1---p---1--- F
>
> Example case 2: A possible formation can be :
>
> F---1---p---1---A---1---p---1---A---1---p---1---A---1---p---1---F
>
> F = flag A = archer p = pikeman
>   ---d--- = distance between pikeman and archer/flag

The first instinct was that the number of pikeman were equal to the number of gaps, but then I realized that there can be a case when, we might that to place two pikeman between 2 archers since the distance of the next archer to the right might have their distance less than the distance between previous two archers.
Can some please help me explain the algorithm for this question.

The problem link::  http://www.codechef.com/CDMS2014/problems/CM1401

Link to one of the accepted solutions:: http://www.codechef.com/viewsolution/5166485

Please help me explain this problem guys.
Thanks in advance.. ;)

Comment: The linked solution maintains a pair of {min,max} distances that signify the range between which a pikeman can be placed. This range is updated as the archers are traversed. If a future archer is placed very far away so that even the 'max' value placement of previous pikeman cannot cater to the next archer, then the number of pikemans is incremented.